# 0-1 Knapsack for large weights

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying to solve the 0-1 Knapsack for the large weights problem. Constraints for the problem are :

1. *All values in input are integers.
2. $$1 \leq N \leq 100$$
3. $$1 \leq W \leq 10^9$$
4. $$1 \leq w_i \leq W$$
5. $$1 \leq v_i \leq 10^3*$$

Below is the code which I have written with comments.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

const int V = 1e5;
const int N = 100;

int main() {
    int n, w, inp1, inp2, max_val = -1;
    vector<pair<int, int>> arr;
    cin >> n >> w; // n - no of items, w - total weight that the knapsack can hold
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> inp1 >> inp2; // ith input : w_i v_i
        arr.push_back({inp1, inp2});
        max_val = max(max_val, inp2); // storing maximum value of an item from the inputs
    }
    unsigned long long int dp[N + 1][V + 1]; // dp[i][j] = min weight that can be obtained from items 0..(i - 1) having total value atmost j 
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (max_val * n); j++){
            if(i == 0 || j == 0)
                dp[i][j] = ULLONG_MAX;
            else if(j >= arr[i].second)
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i - 1][j - arr[i - 1].second] + arr[i - 1].first);
            else
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (max_val * n); j++)
            cout << dp[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    int i; 
    for(i = (max_val * n); i >= 1; i--){
        if(dp[n][i] != ULLONG_MAX && dp[n][i] <= w)
            break;
    }
    cout << i;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am not getting correct answer for all inputs. For example, for input

```
3 8
3 30
4 50
5 60
```

I am getting 180 as answer, whereas 90 is the accurate answer. Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2-D array when weight can be 10^9,
And the complexity of your code is O(n*w).
So that will give TLE in other cases.
Use unordered_map for memoization.

Comment: Actually, the memoization will not help you, the time complexity for memorization is still O(n * W) and It most definitely will give you TLE in OJs. Better is to change the dp states definitions, found this article which has explanation so refer this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knapsack-with-large-weights/